# Notification Builder does not create the notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

Here is the complete code.

```
    import ...

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    public void notify(View view) {

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//shows the toast "Clicked"

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?
This does not create any notifications. I'm fairly new to android and learning on my own. This is the first time I got stuck for a long time. I searched everywhere, and all the resources are telling me the thing which i have already done.
Please help.

Comment: Do you see the Toast coming up?

Comment: Yes!! Toast is getting created but no notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer.

My phone is Oreo. I had to use notification channels. The answers mentioned here worked perfectly fine on the emulator which had a lower version.

Used [GitHub] (https://github.com/tutsplus/android-o-how-to-use-notification-channels) for reference.

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling notify function:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    notify(); //Call here
   }
public void notify() //View is not used

{
// Rest of the code is same
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

//shows the toast "Clicked"

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

If you use

```
public void notify(View view) //View is required

{
```

then call would be : notify(null);

otherwise just calling : notify();

would throw following exception ->

java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()

Comment: I called notify(null) inside onCreate(), but still, no notification is shown.

Comment: Did you try without null?

Comment: It throws the following exception ->
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()

Comment: you have to call notify(); -> should be the last line in onCreate(); with no parameter in public void notify() { ... }